# How do I test the Naive Bayes classifier with totally new data after I train/test?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, anaconda

I train/tested a binary classifier to give me output as 0 or 1 based on class. It is just like a spam classifier. Now, I have some extra data and I just want to test them and get an output array like:

```
[0 1 0 0 0... 1 0]
```

Here is what I did:

I used the pandas library to create a data frame

```
def dataFromDirectory(path):
    rows = []
    index = []
    for filename, message in readFiles(path):
        rows.append({'resume': message})
        index.append(filename)

    return DataFrame(rows, index=index)

test= DataFrame({'resume':[]})
test=test.append(dataFromDirectory(r'<folder path>'))
```

This worked and I successfully created a data frame, with 10 sample .txt files.

So,

```
test.head()
```

will give a 5x2 array of file path and content of the txt file in the two columns respectively. Something like this:

```
         | data   |
<path1>  | <text> |
<path2>  | <text> |
<path3>  | <text> |
 .  
 .
 .
```

But, when I do Tf-Idf transformation:

```
testtf=tf.transform(test) #tf is the Tf-Idf vectorizer
pred1=mnb.predict(testtf) #MultinomialNaiveBayes is mnb
```

I get output as

```
[0]
```

What am I doing wrong? Please note that I am using Python 3.

Comment: You should post the complete code and some samples of `test`. What is `tf`, a TfidfVectorizer?

Comment: @VivekKumar Yes, it is Tfidf vectorizer

Comment: What is `test`. I mean does it contain a list of texts or a single text, or list of files ? Print the shape of `test` and `testtf`.

Comment: testtf is after I vecorize test using Tf-Idf. This should work just like a spam classifier. Like, I have 10 .txt files and when I do mnb.predict(testtf) the output should be an array with 10 elements.

Comment: Post the `test.shape` and try `testtf=tf.transform(test['resume'])`.

Comment: `test.shape()` gives an error "'tuple' object is not callable" but `testtf=tf.transform(test['resume'])` worked for me and I got the desired result. Thank you very much.